# A build scan was not published as you have not authenticated with server 'ge.spring.io'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I'm working on Windows 10 pro, Java 1_8 or Java 1_15. No corporate proxy,
connectivity to the internet works just fine.

I'm trying to build spring-boot from the source.  I cloned the github repo, then checked out the tag that I needed.

```
git clone https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot.git
git checkout tags/v2.3.9.RELEASE
```

It failed to switch to that tag.  It's actually the first time I saw an error while trying to switch to a tag.  That's ok. I deleted that directory, switched to the tag in the browser and downloaded the zip.

I unzipped the directory and then attempted to build with gradle from source.

```
gradlew build
```

I got the following error

```
A build scan was not published as you have not authenticated with server 'ge.spring.io'
```

I originally tried with JDK 1.8 then switched to JDK 15.  Same error both times.
I noticed that spring boot page suggested gradle wrapper.  So I googled on how to do that and found that I needed to run

```
gradle wrapper
```

That produced the same error message.

So I thought maybe I should register with ge.spring.io.  I actually looked into that when I first got the error.  I didn't see any method to register.  So now I looked even deeper and still could not find out how to register.  I googled on how to register, nothing.  I cannot be the only this has ever happened to.  I also find it extremely odd that I cannot register, unless this repo is only for paying customers.  If that is the case it's not really open source.  Just putting the source out there with no way to build the actual binaries, while the source is open is absurd.  So I know this cannot be a paid for sight that I need to register with just to build the source.

I looked through configuration files for where it might be referencing this site, I could not find it.

I thought, maybe the jars had built and it just could not push them to the site.  That's fine I just need to jar files.  However, I cannot find the jar files either.

By now I'm sure you surmised I'm not familiar with gradle, you would be correct.  I can follow instructions on how to run it, but I have never used it n a project.  I've used maven, ant, make and others.

If this error can be ignored, and I should look somewhere for the built jars, that would be the solution I'm looking for.  If I need to register for the site in order to finish the build, then how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message about the build scan can be ignored. A build scan describes what happened during the build and isn’t needed to access the build’s output.

When you run `build`, each module’s jar is written to its `build/libs` directory. For example, you’ll find the jar for the `spring-boot` module in `spring-boot-project/spring-boot/build/libs`. Alternatively, you may want to run `publishToMavenLocal`. It will publish each module to your local Maven cache from where you can consume it in a Maven build, or a Gradle build configured with `mavenLocal()` as a repository.

Comment: There are no build/libs under any directory in spring-boot-project/....

Comment: I switched to my WLS2 ubutnu environment and retried things.  They are building now and I see the jar files in the build/libs diretory.